# is there a way to change the text's font in Cimg?

Tags: visual-c++, graphics, cimg

i wanted to know if i can draw a text in Cimg graphic library draw_text function and change the font of the text to another font ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't load own fonts in CImg, but you can see example https://github.com/tttzof351/CImgAndFreetype for load custom fonts using freetype and render text on bitmap using cimg.

Answer (score 1):

No. CImg's text drawing is very simplistic.

```
CImg<T>& draw_text(const int x0, const int y0,
                   const char *const text,
                   const int, const tc *const background_color,
                   const float opacity, const CImgList<t>& font, ...)
```

`font` is just a `CImgList` of letters (i.e. `font[letter-'a']` is an image of "letter"). Either make your own or use one of the built-in options:

```
static const CImgList<T>& font(const unsigned int font_height, 
                               const bool variable_size=true);
```

or

```
static CImgList<T> _font(const unsigned int *const font, 
                         const unsigned int w, const unsigned int h, 
                         const bool variable_size)
```

where `font` here is one of the predefined fonts at the top of CImg.h such as `font12x24`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean [this](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/annotated.html) Cimg library, a couple of the overloads of [`draw_text`](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#a10f19686ec4d22cf112d7d60a00849eb) take parameters named "font". Those seem like a reasonable starting point...